# I'm getting an error when trying to save a new model with 2 fields referencing different ids in the same table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm new to laravel, and I've picked up the basic workflow of creating, updating and deleting database entries using migrations, models and controllers. But now I'm trying to do the same with a subscriptions table that has a subscriberId and a followeeId in it. Both of these fields reference different ids of the same table (users). This kind of task seem to require some finetuning. And I'm stuck.

Here's my code with some comments.

**Subscriptions Table**

```
Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('subscriberId');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('followeeId');
    $table->foreign('subscriberId')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('followeeId')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Previously, I've used another approach to foreign ids, namely the one with the `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()` pattern, but in this particular case I need to make sure that the two foreign ids reference different users, so I went for a more verbose option.

**User Model**

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class, 'subscriberId');
}
```

Here I've added the second parameter. This seems to work.

**Subscription Model**

```
   class Subscription extends Model
   {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'subscriberId',
        'followeeId'
    ];

    public function subscriberId()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'subscriberId');
    }

    public function followeeId()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'followeeId');
    }
}
```

Here I pass additional parameters, too, although in this case I'm not so sure if these are the correct ones. But this is my best guess. If I'm not mistaken, the second parameter of the belongsTo relation is inferred from the model that *is being passed in*, not the model of the parent class as is the case with the hasMany relation. So in this case that would be 'id' of the users table, which would be the default here anyway, but I need the third parameter, so I explicitly state the second parameter as well. Again, I'm not sure about this combination, but that's what I was able to make of the docs. I've also used other combinations of additional parameters, and even tried getting rid of these two public functions altogether, but that won't work either.

Now, here's the controller. If I do this:

```
$user->subscriptions()->get();
```

I do get the subscriptions I want. But if I do this instead:

```
$user->subscriptions()->create([
        'subscriberId' => 1,
        'followeeId' => 2
    ]);
```

I get the 500 error. I've also tried another approach:

```
    $newSub = new Subscription;
    $newSub->subscriberId = 1;
    $newSub->followeeId = 2;
    $newSub->save();
    return $newSub;
```

But still no success. I still get the 500 error when I try to save()

Please help me out.

Comment: Before anything we need to know the error message of the 500 error either check the response or the log for this.

Comment: Oh, ok. I use React for the front end. Here's what gets logged to the console: app.js:1612 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/subscribe 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:1612
xhrAdapter @ app.js:1438
dispatchRequest @ app.js:2143
request @ app.js:1914
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:1946
wrap @ app.js:2558
handleForm @ resources_js_compone…ogin_index_js.js:32
callCallback @ app.js:26881
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ app.js:26930
invokeGuardedCallback @ app.js:26992
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ app.js:27006
executeDispatch @ app.js:31179

Comment: processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ app.js:31211
processDispatchQueue @ app.js:31224
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ app.js:31235
(anonymous) @ app.js:31444
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ app.js:45327
batchedEventUpdates @ app.js:26681
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ app.js:31443
attemptToDispatchEvent @ app.js:28941
dispatchEvent @ app.js:28860
unstable_runWithPriority @ app.js:59263
runWithPriority$1 @ app.js:34212
discreteUpdates$1 @ app.js:45344
discreteUpdates @ app.js:26692
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ app.js:28825

Comment: a 500 error is on the backend

Comment: Ok. Here's the short version: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table subscriptions has no column named updated_at in laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:486

Comment: So, it is trying to insert created_at and updated_at into the subscriptions table. Maybe, there are some errors with additional parameters, after all

Comment: It finally worked! I should have used public $timestamps = false, and I also misunderstood the docs. But your suggestion to log the server side error was of great help. Somehow it hadn't occurred to me before. Since then I was able to work my way through this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I should have used

```
public $timestamps = false
```

in the Subscription model, and I also misunderstood the docs. The correct combo is

**User Model**

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class, 'subscriberId');
}
```

and

**Subscription Model**

```
public function subscriberId()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'subscriberId');
}

public function followeeId()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'followeeId');
}
```